# Favicon not working under google-chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, favicon

i have a network based on php and html. Now i have the issue, that the favicon doesn't show up in google-chrome. If i use firefox all works well. Any advices?

My Code:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://teabag.webclient2.de/minis/images/favicon.png" />
```

Website: http://teabag.webclient2.de/minis/

Thanks!

Comment: how come that you have two head tags? is your webpage auto generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just checked out your website and noticed you have `<link>` placed in the `<body>` tag.

It should be within the `<head>` of the document instead. In doing so, it will work.

Comment: no its definitely in the <head> section. but i have two <head> sections, can this cause this?

Comment: @progNewFag It's definitely not. Go to the link your provided and inspect the elements on the page with the developer tool. You have it in `<body>` Look: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MbWkp.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="http://teabag.webclient2.de/minis/images/favicon.png" />
```

It worked for my icon :)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cache. Then add this:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://teabag.webclient2.de/minis/images/favicon.png" />
```